# Determine timezone in Rsyslog file

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I would like to determine what time zone a specific log is in. I found this line in the log:

```
Aug 29 07:07:40 gw kernel: rtc_cmos rtc_cmos: setting system clock to 2013-08-29 11:07:08 UTC(1377774428)
```

Does this mean that at the time that triggered, the UTC time was 2013-08-29 11:07:08 UTC(1377774428) making the log time -4? While this line item appears to be a time adjustment, the next line in the log (and many thereafter) remain in the 07 hour.

if you have any light to shed on this, I'd appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Whats with the downvote? This is a perfectly legitimate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All we can say with confidence is that at the time the log was recorded, in the server's local timezone, based on it's local clock, it thought it was "Aug 29 07:07:40"

Given the UTC timestamp, I would expect that your server's timezone is GMT-4.